# Unable to install bedtools on windows 10 ubuntu

Tags: genome, software-installation, bedtools

I am trying to install bedtools on windows 10, but I get an error I don't understand. How can I fix it?

```
Building BEDTools:
=========================================================
DETECTED_VERSION = v2.27.1
CURRENT_VERSION  =
Updating version file.
 * Creating BamTools API
- Building in src/utils/FileRecordTools
  * compiling FileRecordMgr.cpp
make[1]: g++: Command not found
Makefile:36: recipe for target '../../../obj//FileRecordMgr.o' failed
make[1]: *** [../../../obj//FileRecordMgr.o] Error 127
Makefile:186: recipe for target 'src/utils/FileRecordTools' failed
make: *** [src/utils/FileRecordTools] Error 2
```

Comment: Hi there, I suppose you use the bash terminal available at windows 10, is that correct? The error says that you don't have a compiler for c++ called g++. You can try install it by `sudo apt-get install g++`. Then run `make` again.

Comment: Turns out that something went wrong the first time I tried to install g++, but I didn't see the error message.

Answer (score 3):

My personal advice would be to avoid compiling tools like this if you can avoid it, especially where you are using a "barebones" setup like the one you get with WSL Ubunutu as you'll almost always run into dependency issues.

The linux version of `conda` installs just fine in WSL and `bioconda` hae pretty much any bioinformatics package you might need, already compiled.

Answer (score 2):

> make[1](https://www.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs250PreTest/latest/Public/installingACompiler/): g++: Command not found

You do not have g++ installed on your machine.  This is used to compile the bedtools into an executable file.

[Here is a tutorial on installing g++](https://www.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs250PreTest/latest/Public/installingACompiler/)

Comment: If you have admin privileges, the easiest way to install g++ is `sudo apt-get install -y build-essential`.

Comment: @DanielStandage does that work on Windows? I assume the OP is using the newfangled Ubuntu Subsystem for Windows thing, but I don't know if that can install arbitrary packages like that.

Comment: Oops, I missed the "Windows" part and only saw Ubuntu.  It looks like `apt-get` is supported though. https://www.howtogeek.com/261449/how-to-install-linux-software-in-windows-10s-ubuntu-bash-shell/

Comment: I had tried that, but another error popped up without it realizing. However, the following error popped up after entering `make`, and I can't tell if this is critical for the functionality of bedtools:

`- Building main bedtools binary.

done.

- Creating executables for old CLI.

/bin/bash: python: command not found

Makefile:145: recipe for target 'all' failed

make: *** [all] Error 127`

Comment: Please add the new issue to original post.  This is saying that you don't have python installed.  I think that if you don't want to use the legacy CLI (command line interface) you should be all set.  You can try running `bedtools` and see if you get a usage prompt.